# Как кнопку из одного Activity показать в другом

Tags: java, android

У меня есть несколько 'Activity', в каждой из них N-ое количество кнопок 'Button', по нажатию на которые воспроизводится соответствующий звук. И в соответствие к каждой такой кнопке реализована ImageButton добавления в избранное, которая записывает в 'SharedPreferences' параметр boolean с именем соответсвующему номеру кнопки 'Button'("1", "2", "3" и т.д.), которые потом легко можно прогнать через цикл.

```
protected void onCreate(...) {
    ...
    ...

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        int k = i + 1;
        if(settings.getBoolean(String.valueOf(k), false)){
            switch (k) {
                case 1:
                    fav1.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fav2.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    fav3.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    fav4.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    fav5.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    fav6.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    fav7.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    fav8.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Собитие на клик кнопки добавления в избранное.

```
View.OnClickListener playClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.mfav1:
                if(!settings.getBoolean("1", false)) {
                    fav1.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
                    editor.putBoolean("1", true);
                    editor.commit();
                } else {
                    fav1.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.star_off);
                    editor.putBoolean("1", false);
                    editor.commit();
                }
                break;
    ...
}
```

И вот возникла проблема, как можно(если это вообще возможно) кнопку из моего Activity добавить/отобразить в другом Activity и сохранить информацию об этом?

Comment: По-моему в вашем случае лучше использовать фрагменты.

Comment: Прочитал два раза, но так и не понял, зачем нужно `кнопку из моего Activity добавить/отобразить в другом Activity`.

Comment: @МихаилРебров Кажется это то, что я и искал, спасибо)

Comment: @post_zeew В одном Activity все кнопки(звуки) вместе, а в другом только те, что отмеченный избранными.

Comment: @МихаилРебров, я почитал про фрагменты, но в таком случае мне придется создать отдельный xml для каждой кнопки ? Просто у меня их в приложении несколько десятков.

Comment: @Vlad Dogadaev, а чем они все отличаются? я думаю что вы можете пользоваться и одной xml-кой. Вы с LayoutInflater'ом знакомы?